# Code to replace line in a file is duplication lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace few lines in a file. Here is my sample file:

```
input a1;
//Power_off assertion for all power ports (1 per each power domain)
// `assert_Check1
//Start of functional specification here
// always @* reg_z4=Check
```

Here is the python code I wrote to replace lines:

```
import re,sys,fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=True):
    assertPattern=re.match(r'\/\/\s(`assert_.+\)$)',line, re.M)
    alwaysPattern=re.match(r'^\/\/\s(always\s@\*.+\;$)',line, re.M)
    print (line.rstrip().replace('//Power_off assertion for all power ports (1 per each power domain)', '`ifdef assert_stdcell\n\n//Power_off assertion for all power ports (1 per each power domain)'),)
    if assertPattern:
        print (line.rstrip().replace(assertPattern.group(),assertPattern.group(1)))
    print (line.rstrip().replace('//Start of functional specification here','`endif\n\n//Start of functional specification here'),)
    if alwaysPattern:
        print (line.rstrip().replace(alwaysPattern.group(),alwaysPattern.group(1)),)
```

This code does some of the replacement fine. However, the code duplicates all the lines in the file. Furhtermore alwaysPattern and assertPattern replacement is not working. Here is the output of the code:

```
input a1;
input a1;
`ifdef assert_stdcell

//Power_off assertion for all power ports (1 per each power domain)
//Power_off assertion for all power ports (1 per each power domain)
// `assert_Check1
// `assert_Check1
//Start of functional specification here
`endif

//Start of functional specification here
// always @* reg_z4=Check
// always @* reg_z4=Check
```

Any idea why the duplication is happening? and why pattern replacement not working?

Comment: This can't possibly be a minimal example?

Comment: updated post to a smaller example

Answer (score 0):

Duplication is happening because you have to print statements outside of your ifs. So you will always print the line twice, and in addition you would print the line again if any of your reg ex would match (they don't).

Comment: why would it print every line twice though when print statement is telling only to replace certain lines?

Comment: thats not how replace works.  Replace takes a string "s", looks for a pattern and replace it if it finds it, otherwise s  is returned unchanged (and here gets printed by print).

Comment: are you implying I would need separate for loops for each line replacement to fix this?